# Imitate PHP sessions that write instantly

Tags: php, session

I am having a difficult time troubleshooting a given script (the database queries are taking too long on a given server).  To "look" inside the servers when they were running, I thought I would just have the server write to a session periodically as it executes the script, and then have another PHP program display that session.  Unfortunately, it appears that sessions are really only written once for a given script (if there is a way to change this, please advise).

An alternate would be to write to a DB, but as my whole purpose is to test the time it is taking the database, I would rather not.

How would you recommend imitating PHP's session behavior, but so that the values are immediately written?  It doesn't have to be secure because it is just for testing.

Comment: Maybe writing to a text file? A.K.A. standard log file

Comment: Have you tried looking at the mysql server logs? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html - what are you hoping to determine by examining the session?

Comment: In addition to @KaiQing's comment MySQL has a slow query log that logs queries that take longer than a given time.

Comment: You cannot do that easily. You can however define a kind of wrapper for `$_SESSION`, and call a `session_start()`, write the data, & call `session_write_close()` on every alteration. It would have major overhead though. You could opt to store data of longer requests in another storage location (memcache, apc..) instead of the session with some unique identifier, and read that.

Comment: @Babblo.  Yes, was thinking of a text file as well.  Right now playing with flush, and maybe will meet the needs

Comment: @KaiQing  I have a remote VPS and a local server.  They both used to take the same time for a particularly long script (200 seconds).  Now the VPS takes almost forever.  Don't know where the problem is and trying to put triggers in the script.  Guess I could just use the systems log

Comment: @Wrikken.  Interesting approach.  Any additional details?

Comment: On which of the 2? BTW, though of another one: just enable [`profiling`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) if you're using MySQL, and at the very end of a request, write out the result to a file. Then you have it all: what takes how long, and where does it spend its time.